# Is it syntactically correct to put any kind of expressions in c++'s initialization list?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, initializer-list

I came across this class definition from a textbook:

```
class Smiley : public Circle { // use the circle as the base for a face public:

Smiley(Point p, int r) : Circle{p,r}, mouth{nullptr} { }
```

I have a question about the constructor's initialization list. The `Circle{p,r}` part should be about constructing a base object, which does not look like something you put in an initialization list. Does it mean that you can put any kind of expressions in the initialization list?

Comment: *"which does not look like something you put in an initialization list"* - Why not? Where would one initialize bases?

Comment: `Circle{p,r}` is a "call" (not right word really) to the parents class constructor. It lets the parent `Circle` class initialize itself.

Comment: Where else would you put the base object initialization? The constructor body is too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Circle{p,r} part should be about constructing a base object

Correct.

> which does not look like something you put in an initialization list

Regardless of what it looks like to you, the member initialiser list is **the** place to initialise the base sub object. Despite having *member* in its name. Technically, sub object initaliser list would be more accurate name.

> Does it mean that you can put any kind of expressions in the initialization list?

No; It's unclear how you would end up with such conclusion. The grammar of member initialiser list is following:

```
ctor-initializer:
    : mem-initializer-list

mem-initializer-list:
    mem-initializer ... opt
    mem-initializer-list , mem-initializer ... opt

mem-initializer:
    mem-initializer-id ( expression-list opt )
    mem-initializer-id braced-init-list

mem-initializer-id:
    class-or-decltype
    identifier
```

In case of `mem-initializer-id` being `class-or-decltype`, the `mem-initializer` is for a base and in case of `identifier` it is for a member.

Within the expression-list, you cannot put any arbitrary kinds of expressions either. The grammar is:

```
expression-list:
    initializer-list

initializer-list:
    initializer-clause ... opt
    initializer-list , initializer-clause ... opt

initializer-clause:
    assignment-expression
    braced-init-list

braced-init-list:
    { initializer-list , opt }
    { designated-initializer-list , opt }
    { }
```